# Solution of the fractional Laplace equation on a ball

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

What is the expression of the (non $u \equiv 0$) solutions to
\begin{align*}
(-\Delta)^s u &= 0 && x \in B_r(0) \\
u&=0 && x \in \mathbb R^N \setminus B_r(0),
\end{align*}
where $$
(-\Delta)^s u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{N+2s}} dy,
$$  ($0<s<1$)
is the fractional Laplacian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Martin kernel* and *Martin representation* is what you are after. Positive solutions are:
$$ u(x) = \int_{\partial B_r} \frac{(1 - |x|^2)^s}{|x - y|^N} \, \mu(dy) $$
for any positive measure $\mu$. Signed solution can also be of that form with signed $\mu$, but there are other (more singular) solutions, too.

In other words: take a classical harmonic function $v$ and multiply it by $(1 - |x|^2)^{s-1}$ to get a $(2s)$-harmonic function $u$.

This result is due to Hmissi:

- F. Hmissi, *Fonctions harmoniques pour les potentiels de Riesz sur la boule unité*, Expo. Math. 12(3) (1994), 281–288.

Comment: Thank you. If $s=1$, and we assume that $u$ is radially symmetric we get $u(x) = C_1\frac{r}{N} + C_2 \frac{1}{r^{N-1}}$. Is there an analogue of this result for $s \in (0,1)$? In particular, it looks that $u(x)$ from your answer has always a singularity, while this does not for $C_2 = 0$

Comment: Radial solutions for $s = 1$ are just constants, and $u(x) = C_1 + C_2 |x|^{2-N}$ are solutions in the punctured ball $B_r \setminus \{0\}$. Analogous result is available for the fractional Laplace operator, $u(x) = C_1 |x|^{s-1} + C_2 G_B(x/r,0)$, where $G_B$ is the *Green function* for $(-\Delta)^s)$ in the unit ball. You may like to have a look at my survey: M. Kwaśnicki, *Fractional Laplace Operator and its Properties*, in: A. Kochubei, Y. Luchko, *Handbook of Fractional Calculus with Applications. Vol. 1: Basic Theory*, De Gruyter, Berlin, 2019, it lists many results for the ball.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference! What if we look for solutions in the form $u(x) = v(\rho)\omega$, with $\omega \in {S}^{N-1}$ and $\rho \in (0,r)$?
For $s=1$, we have $v(\rho) = \frac{c_1}{N}\rho + \frac{c_2}{\rho^{N-1}}$. What is the fractional analogue of this expression?

Comment: If I understand correctly — this is again very similar, by *Bochner's relation*. I discuss it briefly in section 3.4 of the survey linked above, and in more detail in a joint paper with Bartłomiej Dyda and Alexey Kunzetsov, *Fractional Laplace operator and Meijer G-function*, Constructive Approx. 45(3) (2017): 427–448, https://doi.org/10.1007/s00365-016-9336-4. The solution should be $v(\rho)=C_1 \rho(1-\rho)^{s-1} + C_2 \rho g(\rho)$, where $g(\rho)$ is the radial profile of $G_B(x,0)$ in dimension $N + 2$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you add some more explanation about what is the Bochner's relation and how it produces the solution $v(\rho) = C_1 \rho(1-\rho)^{s-1} + C_2\rho g(\rho)$. By the way, is it correct to say that, if $v$ is also s-harmonic in $B_r$ then $C_2 \equiv 0$?

Comment: Is there anything particular that you would like to ask about? Explaining Bochner's relation would not fit into this comment, I think. Regarding the other part of your comment: yes, if $C_2 \ne 0$, then $v$ is not harmonic near the origin.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, in particular, I'd like to know how you use it to compute $v(\rho)$ if it seems to be about problems in the whole space

Comment: I put this additional question in another post. Let me know if you have any remarks: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384757/fractional-laplacian-equation-on-a-ball-and-explicit-solutions Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I am not aware of any explicit results for annular regions. Regarding the punctured ball, *Bochner's relation* and the *Green function of a ball* are discussed in both papers that I mentioned, what else do you need?